# Detect the user triggering the build in VS2012 using MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I am using VS2012, I have a target but i only want it to execute it when it equals a particular value. Now the value i would like to use is the "requested by" description in TFS 2010 which indicates the user that raised the build.

But i do not know yet how to detect the user who raised the build in the MSBuild framework.

Does anyone know how i could go about implementing this? I have a looked in the Well Known Metadata of MSBuild and it doesn't contain the metadata i would like.

Below is my target:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="Release">
<Message Text="..RUNNING TESTS.." />
<PropertyGroup>
  <TestSuccessOrNot>1</TestSuccessOrNot>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command='"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:C:\\Tests\\MyUnitTests.dll /test:T5278 /detail:testname '>
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot" />
</Exec>
<Error Condition="$(TestSuccessOrNot) == 1" Text="Unit tests fail!" />
```

Ideally i would like to pass that value(user that raised the build) into the Condition attribute of my target.

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The properties are `RequestedBy` and `RequestedFor`, but not sure when they differ. The condition should look like `Condition=" '$(RequestedBy)' == 'anyUserName'"` For users this will be the display name, while for triggered builds it will be `[CollectionName]\Project Collection Service Accounts`